# ActiveRecord::Base SQL result object types different in MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Am I missing something?  Same console, same codebase, different database connections. Result: different object types returned. If MySQL is used, we get an array of arrays, if PostgreSQL is used, we get an array of hashes.

### Example classes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
end

class Series < ActiveRecord::Base
   establish_connection postgres_database_hash
   ...
end
```

### With a MySQL connection

```
> User.connection.execute('SELECT * from users limit 2').to_a
   (211.0ms)  SELECT * from users limit 2
 => [[1, "jmetta", "jmetta@gmail.com"], [2, "johnmetta", "jmetta+test@gmail.com"]]
```

### With a Postgres connection

```
> Series.connection.execute('SELECT * from series limit 2').to_a
   (107.1ms)  SELECT * from series limit 2
 => [{"id"=>"29", "enr_id"=>"114118", "ent_id"=>"164",}, {"id"=>"30", "enr_id"=>"114110", "ent_id"=>"164"}]
```

### Coda

It seems that, at this level of abstraction where `to_a` is asked to give a result, the result should be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you're missing is that `execute` is a very low-level connection to the underlying database driver that is most useful for sending SQL DDL ([Data Definition Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language)) into the database to manually alter tables, add constraints and indexes that AR doesn't understand, etc. If you want to send raw queries into the database and get raw results back, you should use the slightly higher level [`select_rows`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_rows) instead:

```
User.connection.select_rows('SELECT * from users limit 2').each do |row|
  # `row` is an Array of Strings here
end
```

A `select_rows` call should give you an array-of-arrays-of-strings with any database.

`execute` will return whatever the underlying driver returns, `select_rows` will return something consistent.

Comment: I've actually never seen select_rows, which means there's a *lot* of code in my codebase that should probably be updated. This is beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: It is a shame we don't have a consistent low-level database interface like Perl's `DBI` in Ruby, ORMs really don't cut it for a lot of things.

Comment: Agreed. I am spending a lot of time in SQL with _actual_ DDL commands, and I'm trying to do as much as I can as close to Ruby as I can. It seems that when I do that, I break more than I want (because I'm thinking of the ORM as a strong low-level layer, but also because I need to RTFM a bit more, it seems)

Comment: I'm one of those weirdoes that thinks the database should manage data so I have triggers, CHECK constraints, ... all over the place; I also like to use "advanced" SQL like CTEs, derived tables, window functions, ... so I have to push the ORM out of the way all the time (and then complain about how dumb ORMs are, even the ORMs I've written myself :)

Comment: if you have a problems with raw SQL in strings use [sql_query](https://github.com/sufleR/sql_query) gem. That solved a lot of my problems with advanced SQL.